# Want to place all .o files into a directory, but make stops after compilng fist one

Tags: makefile

I want to have a neat makefile containing explicit dependencies but placing all .o objects in a separate directory to link it altogether later (in an another file).

The problem is that my make stops after compiling the first source and then stops with no error whatsoever.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -pedantic -std=c99

DIR=../obj

$(DIR)/CList.o : CList.c CList.h CList_aux.h Observation.h CList_View_aux.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) CList.c -o $@
$(DIR)/CList_aux.o : CList_aux.c CList.h CNode.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) CList_aux.c -o $@
$(DIR)/CList_View_aux.o : CList_View_aux.c CNode.h Observation.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) CList_View_aux.c -o $@
$(DIR)/CNode.o : CNode.c CNode.h CNode_aux.h Observation.h CList.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) CNode.c -o $@
$(DIR)/CNode_aux.o : CNode_aux.c CNode.h Observation.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) CNode_aux.c -o $@
$(DIR)/Observation.o : Observation.c Observation.h Observation_aux.h CNode.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Observation.c -o $@
$(DIR)/Observation_aux.o : Observation.c Observation.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Observation_aux.c -o $@
$(DIR)/Record.o : Record.c Record.h Observation.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Record.c -o $@
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `make` builds the first target in the makefile.  In this case, that is `${DIR}/CList.o`.

You need a different first target, conventionally called `all`:

```
OBJECTS = \
    $(DIR)/CList.o \
    $(DIR)/CList_aux.o \
    $(DIR)/CList_View_aux.o \
    $(DIR)/CNode.o \
    $(DIR)/CNode_aux.o \
    $(DIR)/Observation.o \
    $(DIR)/Observation_aux.o

all: ${OBJECTS}
```

Note that this works whether there are any object files in the `${DIR}` or not; a wildcard looking for object files in the directory makes sure that those that have already been compiled once are up to date, but doesn't try building those which failed to compile previously, or simply aren't there.

Answer (score 0):

If the Makefile is really just as much as you posted, then you're missing the `all:` rule. Without having an explicit `all` rule, make assumes that the first present rule is to be made, so it stops after that. In order to achieve what you want, add (append) this to the Makefile (change the final executable name respectively):

```
OBJECTS = $(wildcard $(DIR)/*.o)

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
        $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: If I do `rm $DIR/*.o`, nothing gets rebuilt.  Nothing that fails to compile gets rebuilt either — does it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I use this pattern and it tends to work. Maybe I had a typo here?